# AG listener creation failed SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, listener

I'm getting the error below while creating an AG listener in SQL Server.

> Ensure that the network adapters for dependent IP address resources have access to at least one DNS server. Alternatively, enable NetBIOS for dependent IP addresses.

The user has full privileges and it can create a computer object and a DNS entry successfully.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Are you able to share the cluster log?

Comment: 000005bc.000026b4::2018/12/04-15:42:11.578 WARN  [API] s_ApiOpenNodeEx: Node TEST3 failed, status = 5042
0000021c.000023e0::2018/12/04-15:42:13.587 WARN  [RES] Network Name <AG_LISTENER>: NetName::Dns::PingNameInternal: (11010)' because of '[cxl::Pinger-"LISTENER"] Could not send IPv4 echo.'

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the cluster's user account can create computer objects in Active Directory. See [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alwaysonpro/2014/03/25/create-listener-fails-with-message-the-wsfc-cluster-could-not-bring-the-network-name-resource-online/) for the specific steps you need to do in Active Directory Users and Computers to grant the permissions. By default, the cluster does NOT have the rights it needs and the AG wizard doesn't really do anything to warn you or to grant those rights for you.

Comment: It has permission and i can see newly created object(ag listener name)

Answer (score 0):

This server is in hyper-v and Always on listener creation use hyper-v host IP's send packets to DNS server. Once we enabled access in network level, The issue got fixed.